# Why do I get an error when I typedef auto?

Tags: c++, c++11

I thought this would work.

```
typedef auto var;
```

But I get the error:

> `error: typedef declared 'auto'`

Contrarily, it works with any other keyword:

```
typedef int num;
```

Why am I getting an error?

Comment: You might try `#define var auto`; if you are at it, use also `#define begin {`, `#define end }` etc.

Comment: Don't try to write another language in C++ - write idiomatic C++ so that your maintainers know what you did.

Comment: @anatolyg: You might want to make it more clear that you can do that, but seriously **don't**. People might think that your solution is a gread idea otherwise...

Comment: For some reason, the site doesn't let me edit my comment; anyway: what i wrote is possible but NOT recommended, because it makes code harder to understand.

Comment: @Grizzly - had anatolyg just said "You might try `#define var auto`" and left it at that his response might have been taken the wrong way. His "if you are at it, ..." makes it pretty clear that his response was a sarcastic suggestion.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Theoretical it's clear. However I have met "programmers", who might actually think that the other mentioned examples are also great ideas and would consider going with the full set.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply, this is not an allowed use of `auto`.  `typedef` defines an alias for a type.  `auto` is not a type; when used in the declaration of a variable, it is a stand-in for the type of the initializer.  If you were able to `typedef auto var;`, then `var` would not be an alias for *a type*.

Answer (score 0):

auto is a type modifier not a type and so cannot be typedef'ed

Comment: That is no longer true in C++11.

Comment: It's completely true. `auto` is not a type in C++11.

Comment: @DeadMG: but it's not a type modifier in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it because auto is not really a type.
If you want to use `var` instead of `auto` then you can do it like this:

```
#define var auto
```

But doing it this way can lead to problems, because after that line every `var` in code will be replaced with `auto`. Including included files. For example

```
int var= 0;
```

will become

```
int auto= 0;
```

And that will break compilation.

So if you gona go this road remember to include all header files before that define.